# C++ Error: identifier "barCode" is undefined

Tags: c++, identifier

on line 34 of ZipCode.cpp my compiler (MS Visual Studios 2013) is giving me Error: identifier "barCode" is undefined. Here is my header file ZipCode.h:

```
#ifndef _ZIPCODE_H
#define _ZIPCODE_H

#include <string>

class ZipCode {

private:
    std::string barCode;//The Bar Code
    void convDigit(int);//Converts a single digit to its bar code equivalent 
public:
    ZipCode(int);//Constructor recieving a zip code
    ZipCode(std::string);//Constructor recieving a bar code
    int getZipCode(void);//Returns the zip code
    std::string getBarCode(void);//Returns the bar code
};

#endif
```

Source code ZipCode.cpp:

```
#include "ZipCode.h"

#include <string>

ZipCode::ZipCode(std::string a){
    barCode = a;
}

ZipCode::ZipCode(int a){
    barCode = "";
    for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++){
        int digit = a % 10;
        a /= 10;
        convDigit(digit);
        }
}

void ZipCode::convDigit(int a){
    switch (a){
    case 0: barCode = std::string("11000") + barCode; break;
    case 1: barCode = std::string("00011") + barCode; break;
    case 2: barCode = std::string("00101") + barCode; break;
    case 3: barCode = std::string("00110") + barCode; break;
    case 4: barCode = std::string("01001") + barCode; break;
    case 5: barCode = std::string("01010") + barCode; break;
    case 6: barCode = std::string("01100") + barCode; break;
    case 7: barCode = std::string("10001") + barCode; break;
    case 8: barCode = std::string("10010") + barCode; break;
    case 9: barCode = std::string("10100") + barCode; break;
    }
}

std::string getBarCode(){
    return (barCode);//Error: identifier "barCode" is undefined
}
```

In the previous three functions I use barCode and there is no problem there, so I'm confused why there is now a problem in getBarCode(). I've tried:

```
return (ZipCode::barCode)//Error: member ZipCode::barCode is inaccessible.
return (this->barCode)//Error: 'this' may only be used inside a non-static member function.
```

Both of the above errors also confuse me, because barCode and getBarCode are both members of the ZipCode class, and getBarCode is not a static function. I'm still new to programming (if it isn't obvious) and I'm especially new to C++. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undeclared Identifier Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131193/undeclared-identifier-issue). Summary: you need `std::string ZipCode::getBarCode(){`

Comment: `std::string getBarCode()` should be `std::string ZipCode::getBarCode()`, just like you did with `convDigit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other methods you define, it needs to be qualified with the name of the class its in, so

```
std::string ZipCode::getBarCode() {
```